# Conditionally invoking autocmd by file location

Tags: vim

In an `.vimrc` file, is it possible to only execute an autocmd if the file is loaded from a particular directory?

In MacVim, i have a line of code in my `.vimrc` which automatically cds to the directory that contains the file i am editing - however it causes an error when i access the git files that :Gedit creates (vim package *fugitive*).

The autocmd is:

```
autocmd BufEnter * execute "chdir ".escape(expand("%:p:h"), ' ')
```

The error is:

```
Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "*":
```

From `:echo expand("%")` it is clear that Fugitive creates paths that begin with `fugitive:///`, so i am trying to figure out how to test if the first 12 characters of a file's path == `fugitive:///`

Comment: `set autochdir` may solve your problem. But what do you mean with "remote files"? `:Gedit` doesn't edit remote files.

Comment: hmm, right you are. i had assumed that it must have referenced a web repo, as it broke my command ... now i _am_ curious as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think I've misunderstood. Your are changing the directory in the shell, not in Vim, don't you? In that case, autochdir won't be enough.

`:Gedit` creates a temporary file with a funky name:

```
:e vimrc
:Gedit ~2
:echo expand("%")
fugitive:///home/romainl/.vim/.git//8aece3dc3c19522c33c997bc82a2487e3bdf013b/vimrc
:echo expand("%:p:h")
fugitive:///home/romainl/.vim/.git//8aece3dc3c19522c33c997bc82a2487e3bdf013b/
```

There's no way your shell is going to `cd` to that "directory" because it is not a valid path.

However, I have `set autochdir` which tells vim to `cd` automatically to the directory containing the current file. Thanks to that I can see that the temporary file is in:

```
:pwd
/tmp/vGiSmH2
```

I could use the output of `:pwd` to `cd` there.

Comment: +1 for explanation. thanks, this solves my current problem.  I guess the key to making an autocmd conditional is looking to see if the file begins with `fugitive:///`.

Comment: Yes, that's most likely. Why do you `cd` to that directory? Do you execute the file?

Comment: its just legacy `.vimrc` and can come out. i'm learning fugitive just now: It's a very useful package, so i am okay with some things being changed to make it work - just figuring out what _needs_ to be done, and what can be worked around.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `strpart` function.

I ended up settling on the following:

```
if strpart(expand("%:p:h"), 0, 15) == "/Users/myputer/"
   autocmd BufEnter * execute "chdir ".escape(expand("%:p:h"), ' ')
endif
```

Which will only `cd` to a folder if it begins with `/Users/myputer/`

Comment: Saved my day. I used this to run a command *only* when not editing remote files via `scp://`.

Comment: Glad it helped. I was surprised how hard it was to find this answer.

Comment: For documentation sake, the line I used was `if strpart(expand("%:p:h"), 0, 7) == "scp://" ...`

Answer (score 1):

There's a [ticket for this issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/3).

```
autocm BufEnter * if expand('%:p') !~ '://' | :lchdir %:p:h | endif
```

This works well.